# Property-based injection with an Abstract Class

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to add an Abstract method to serialize my response objects in order to hash the id's. That would require to have a property-based injection in order to not pass lots of variables through the constructor.

The class that will be used to Serialize :

```
import { AbstractHash } from 'src/global/abstract.hash';
import { IItems } from '../items.interface';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ResponseItem extends AbstractHash implements IItems {
  name: string;
  price: number;
  type: string;

  constructor(partial: Partial<IItems>) {
    super();
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

The abstract class :

```
import { HashIdHelper } from 'src/hash-id.helper';
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export abstract class AbstractHash {
  @Exclude()
  id: number;

  //@Inject('HASHID_HELPER') // Neither works
  @Inject(HashIdHelper)
  public readonly hashIdHelper: HashIdHelper;

  @Expose({ name: 'id' })
  encodedId() {
    console.log(this.hashIdHelper); // -> undefined
    console.log(HashIdHelper);
    return this.hashIdHelper.encode(this.id);
  }
}
```

The controller :

```
// imports

@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Controller('items')
export class ItemsController {
  constructor(
    private readonly itemsService: ItemsService,
    @Inject('HASHID_HELPER') private readonly hash: HashIdHelper, // <-- Ok
  ) {}


  @Get(':id')
  async findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    console.log(this.hash.encode(+id)); // <-- Ok
    const item = await this.itemsService.findOne(parseInt(id));

    console.log(new ResponseItem(item));
    return new ResponseItem(item); // <-- undefined attribute, see above
  }

}
```

The repository : https://github.com/befabry/caddie/tree/hash_id

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `new ClassInstance()` so you are 100% in control of the class and it's properties. Nest will not inject anything on a manually instantiated class, because it's not managed by Nest's lifecycle in the first place. You can use `moduleRef.create` to have Nest create an instance for you, but once you use the keyword `new` you are in charge of that instance.